# How to bend a sinusoid into a circle in Sverchok?

Tags: sverchok

What's the best way in Sverchok to create a circular sinusoid, like I drew here with the grease pencil?

[image]

I can imagine one one:

1) displace the circle vertices along their normal; or
2) generate a sin curve and wrap it around an origin point

Or maybe there is a third way? Is one of these methods preferable, or more generically useful, from a Sverchok perspective? What would the node setup be?

Comment: Here's an example using a simple scaling factor of the given geometry driven by the sine function https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVFSq.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdBxI.png. There is also the SN: Petal_sine node that can be used to make a similar shape. I think that using one kind of implementation rather than onother strictly depends on the particular needs of the situation. Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 2):

use simple translate node and x+1 hack to fit vertices
[image]